# SOQL Polymorphism; Lead owner

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have to display a list of Leads along with the Owner's Name in a Visualforce page using a custom controller to fetch the data and pass it back.

My main issue is when I display Lead, and click the Lead's Owner field on the VF page. I want it to take me to the Owner's Chatter profile. The use case is for a partner User's Contact record.

For a Queue->to Q page, the Lead owner is a polymorphic field. It can either refer to a User or a Group.

How can I do this in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are asking how to determine if the Owner is a User or a Group. You can do that like so:

```
String userPrefix = User.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(); // '005'
if (String.valueOf(someLead.OwnerId).startsWith(userPrefix))
{
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```

---

I posted this answer quite a while ago, might be worth updating. It's more straightforward to compare the Id type directly.

```
if (someLead.OwnerId.getSObjectType() == User.sObjectType)
```

If you're querying for the records, you can also filter on `Owner.Type`:

```
List<Lead> records = [SELECT ... FROM Lead WHERE Owner.Type = 'User'];
```